# How to design a function generator (Arduino Nano) to filter out noise of different signals?

Tags: arduino, waveform, sine

I have an Arduino Nano-based function (sine, sawtooth, triangular, square) generator. Basically it is an Arduino Nano connected to a MCP4802 DAC, whose output is connected to an RC lowpass filter. Currently I have a cut-off frequency of 150 Hz.

The DAC will output 4 V, then it is connected to the RC filter, where R = 100 Ω and C = 10 μF.

The problem is that I can filter out noise on sine wave, however, this filter distorts the square, sawtooth, and triangular signal (which is obvious, since we filter out high-frequency harmonics from sawtooth, triangular, and square wave signals).

Is there a proper way to design an RC filter on the output and at the same time not distort other waveforms (but instead filter out the noise)?

Comment: There is, but you need to know where the noise comes from and what you want to filter out and what bandwidth you need to pass. In theory, a square wave has infinitely fast edges, so it has infinite bandwidth requirement.

Comment: What noise are you trying to remove?  You do know that the MCP4802 is not designed for speed, right?  You can probably get audio range signals out of it, but not much more.

Comment: How quickly (microseconds) does the Nano send the next **waveform sample** to MCP4802? This update-rate *must* be much higher than the period of the output waveform you're trying to generate...(you mention a waveform period of 1/150 seconds).

Comment: @glen_geek if only I could know that speed :), I have no idea how quickly it does that. 150 Hz I've simply put without any special purpose. I mean, I have just decided that I want to pass under 150Hz signals and attenuate over 150 Hz signals, however 150 Hz is so low frequency which will very heavily destroy the square waveform, for example, where we have infinite number of high freq. harmonics... so that was my problem. I wish to filter out noise (if there is a sudden signal over 150 Hz but at the same time preserve all 4 waveforms I've been mentioned (saw, triangle, square, sine))

Comment: How many data points of your sine wave are you sending per second?  You should be able to see the individual steps on an oscilloscope.  Say you measure the steps as 1 millisecond long.  That means you are putting out one thousand steps per second.  From that you could work out the maximum reasonable cut off frequency for your filter.

Comment: @JRE I should choose very high cutoff frequency so my square wave (as well as triangular and sawtooth) remain unattenuated, but choosing high cutoff will allow any high frequency noise (from environment) to be included into final signal, that what I don't want..

Comment: What if you removed the noise caused by environment before it affects DAC output, instead of removing noise on DAC output? On the other hand you need to remove the square waves caused by DAC update rate. It is called a DAC reconstruction filter. Without it even the sine wave has a staircase waveform of zero order hold circuit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Is there a proper way to design an RC filter on the output and at the
> same time not distort other waveforms (but instead filter out the
> noise)?*

No there isn't. If you want to have a sinewave low-pass filter set a little higher than the sinewave frequency then sure, it will be a benefit for sinewave purity but, given the harmonic content of triangle and square waves it will be an absolute killer. Harmonic content of non-sine-waves: -

[image]

Image from [HyperPhysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Audio/geowv.html). The base (fundamental) frequency is the left-side vertical bar and note, that for a sinewave, only this bar appears in the spectrum hence, applying any linear filter will not alter the sinewave shape (only the amplitude). Here's how a square wave is made up of harmonics (a gif file demonstration): -

[image]

Image from [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:SquareWave.gif).

So, I suggest that you activate the filter (using a MOSFET) when generating a sinewave and, when producing other waveforms (square, triangle etc.) you deactivate the filter so it has very little effect on the wave-shape.

Comment: This is the clearest explanation! I only left with the question about noise. I mean the purpose of RC filter there was to smooth the output signal (due to the Capacitor response) and to attenuate any high frequency noise (from environment etc). While sine wave is filtered, other signals remain stepped and non-defended from noise. Is there some way to smooth the other signals though and secure them from noise?

Comment: What is your question? @ojacomarket

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Your question is not updated and neither should it be because I have made an answer. If you want to update your question please make sure that you clearly show where you have edited it and state that you have made an update after my answer was given. However, it's far preferable to raise a question as a comment under my answer @ojacomarket

Comment: Sorry, I meant my question inside comments here (about noise and smoothing the other waveforms than sine).

Comment: OK, you added to your comment. The best way is use more resolution but, if you want a filter, you should set it at a much higher cut-off frequency and live with the slight distortion it will produce. @ojacomarket

Comment: To sum up, just to be sure I understood it correctly. For all 4 signals I should choose appropriate cutoff frequencies and therefore should have 4 separate RC filters (maybe for square wave it is redundant, so it could be 3 filters). Once RC values are set, I should use switches (either MOSFET or just switch) to toggle between filters depending on the signal is produced, am I correct?

Comment: You are correct @ojacomarket

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Accepted and upvoted, thank you very much!

Comment: You might also consider that a sinewave is symmetrical from -1 to +1 so, you only need to store half a waveform of points. You run up the points to produce -1 to +1 then run down the points (count down) to produce +1 to -1.

Comment: I'm currently just storing all of them inside an array, if that will cost me a frequency a lot, then I will shift on that solution, definitely. All waves are from 0 to 5V having center point at 2.5 V